# Is "water boils at 100 degrees Celsius" both a sufficiency and necessity causal claim?

Tags: logic

Is the claim that heating water to 100 degrees Celsius (the boiling point of water) at sea level causes it to boil both a sufficiency and necessity causal claim?

I am confused on this, I most definitely know that it is a necessity causal claim because water cannot boil unless it is heated to 100 degrees Celsius. But would it also be a sufficiency claim because the sun could heat it or is that already included in the phrase? I might be thinking too much into this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"heating water to 100 degrees Celsius (the boiling point of water) at sea level" is a sufficent reason to boil water.

But it is **not** necessary:

When you boil water on a mountain top, where air pressure is less than at sea level, you can boil water at a temperature less than 100 degrees Celsius.

Comment: It also is not sufficient, because altitude is not the sole determinant of pressure (consider a pressure cooker).

Comment: @Ben Voigt I assume: The questioner considers that the term "at sea level" means "at atmospheric conditions at sea level".

Answer (score 2):

Causal relations are typically neither necessary nor sufficient. In the case of your water boiling example, one can heat water to 100 degrees without it boiling because it may become superheated, so it is not sufficient.

Mackie in his book Cement of the Universe analysed causation as an INUS condition, meaning an insufficient but non-redundant part of an unnecessary but sufficient condition. Quite a mouthful. Understanding what we mean by causal claims however is a lot more complex than simply looking at conditions. We typically use causal claims to explain things. If you want to understand causality further I can recommend Woodward's book "Making Things Happen" and if you have a good head for mathematics you might like Judea Pearl's book on Causality.